# ¿Cómo buscar un nodo en BinarySearchTree/árbol binario (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, árboles-binarios

Tengo un árbol binario formado por algunos nodos que también son BinarySearchTree. No hay clase "Node", sino que cada nodo es un BinarySearchTree. El árbol binario de búsqueda tiene estas propiedades:

```javascript
function BinarySearchTree(valor) {
  this.value = valor;
  this.left = null;
  this.right = null;
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function (value) {
  if (value.horario < this.value.horario) {
    if (this.left === null) {
      var newTree = new BinarySearchTree(value);
      this.left = newTree;
    } else {
      this.left.insert(value);
    }
  } else {
    if (this.right === null) {
      var newTree = new BinarySearchTree(value);
      this.right = newTree;
    } else {
      this.right.insert(value);
    }
  }
};

BinarySearchTree.prototype.size = function () {
  if (this.value.horario === null) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (this.left === null && this.right === null) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (this.left === null) {
    return 1 + this.right.size();
  }

  if (this.right === null) {
    return 1 + this.left.size();
  }

  return 1 + this.left.size() + this.right.size();
};
```

Cada nodo es un objeto con el nombre de una película, horario, día y mes. Ej:

```javascript
{nombre: "Harry Potter", horario: 7, cartelera {dia: 2022, mes: 12}
```

Los nodos varían en sus datos (nombre, horario, etc).
Me piden que, dado un objeto nodo (de nombre string) pasado por parámetro, lo busque en el árbol y me lo devuelva en forma de array así: Ej:

```javascript
[{nombre: "300", horario: 29, dia: 2023, mes: 10}].
```

El árbol está ordenado por horario de película (los más chicos a la izquierda y los más grandes a la derecha).

Ejemplo:

```
// Dado el siguiente árbol:
//❕EL ÁRBOL ESTÁ ORDENADO SEGÚN EL HORARIO DE LA PELÍCULA❕
// { nombre: "Harry Potter", horario: 7, cartelera: { dia: 2022, mes : 12}}
//                                                                   /                           \
// { nombre: "Harry Potter", horario: 06, cartelera: { dia: 2000, mes : 11}}          { nombre: "300", horario: 23, cartelera: { dia: 2004, mes : 09}}
//                                                                                                \
//                                                                                      { nombre: "La historia de Jack", horario: 29, cartelera: { dia: 2013, mes : 10}}
//
//  BinarySearchTree.obtenerPelicula({ nombre: "300", horario: 23, cartelera: { dia: 2004, mes : 09}}) Devuelve ➡
//  [{ nombre: "300", horario: 23, dia: 2004, mes : 09}]
//
//  BinarySearchTree.obtenerPelicula({ nombre: "La historia de Jack", horario: 29, cartelera: { dia: 2013, mes : 10}}) Devuelve ➡
//  [{ nombre: "La historia de Jack", horario: 29, dia: 2013, mes : 10}]
```

Al momento de ejecutar los tests, así se construye el árbol. Crea un nodo inicial "peli" y luego inserta otros nodos. El árbol está ordenado por horario de película (los más chicos a la izq y los más grandes a la der):

```
describe('Ejercicio 09 -  obtenerPeliculas() ', () => {
   test('Recorrer el árbol y las pelÍculas que coincidan con la solicitada. Devolver en un arerglo toda la data acomodada ', () => {
      const peli = new BinarySearchTree({ nombre: 'Morbius', horario: 23 });

      peli.insert({
         nombre: 'Harry Potter',
         horario: 7,
         cartelera: { dia: 2022, mes: 12 },
      });
      peli.insert({
         nombre: 'Los 300',
         horario: 9,
         cartelera: { dia: 2004, mes: 9 },
      });
      peli.insert({
         nombre: 'Harry Potter',
         horario: 20,
         cartelera: { dia: 2000, mes: 11 },
      });
      peli.insert({
         nombre: 'La historia de Jack',
         horario: 23,
         cartelera: { dia: 2013, mes: 10 },
      });

      expect(
         peli.obtenerPelicula({
            nombre: 'Harry Potter',
            horario: 7,
            cartelera: { dia: 2022, mes: 12 },
         })
      ).toEqual([{ nombre: 'Harry Potter', horario: 7, dia: 2022, mes: 12 }]);
```

¿Por qué no me funciona este código? ¿Cómo lo arreglo?

`````javascript
BinarySearchTree.prototype.obtenerPelicula = function (string, array = []) {
  
  if (this.value === string) {
    array = [{
      nombre: string.nombre,
      horario: string.horario,
      cartelera: string.cartelera.dia,
      mes: string.cartelera.mes
    }];

    return array;
  }

  if (string.horario < this.value.horario) return this.left.obtenerPelicula(string, array);
  if (string.horario > this.value.horario) return this.right.obtenerPelicula(string, array);
};
````
`````

Comment: Hola TheHacker, el código lo tienes que poner como texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y lo agregues, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
De paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: las indicaciones tambien como texto.

Comment: Debes poner un ejemplo del árbol

Comment: Te explico: Para dar una respuesta debo probarla antes, para eso necesito el árbol. Tu agregaste llamadas a funciones que no interesan y solo es ruido. Puedes agregar el árbol como una estructura (parecido a lo que es JSON) o en base a llamadas de tu función insert, pero si lo haces con esto último debes agregar la implementación del insert.  [mre]